# Cannot connect to AWS RDS PostgreSQL instance from local machine

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-web-services, psycopg2

I have created a AWS RDS PostgreSQL instance with public access enabled but I am unable to connect to it. Here is my code:

```
try:
   conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname="elevate_permission",
                            user="postgres",
                            password="password123",
                            host="database-1.ce2ilrafe9ry.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com")
   print("Connected to DB")
except psycopg2.OperationalError as e:
   logger.error(e)
   sys.exit()
```

[image: Endpoint and port]
[image: Database name, username and password]

**EDIT**
I've added the above exception to my code above, this is the error message I receive:

> Operation timed out. Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connection?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the complete and exact error message you get.

Comment: As with all errors print the actual error message, don't just catch any errors and simply ignore them. And then https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/rds-cannot-connect

Comment: Was the instance launched with `Publicly Accessible = Yes`? Was the instance launched in a Public Subnet? What is the configuration of the Security Group associated with the RDS server?

Comment: Hi @JohnRotenstein, these are the [Security Group configurations](https://imgur.com/a/wMxFuc1). The Publicly Accessible option is selected

Answer (score 5):

The screenshot showing your Security Group is indicating that you are using a Security Group called `default`. It is unlikely to be permitting an Inbound connection on port 5432 (which is used by Postgres).

I recommend the following:

- **Create a new Security Group** in the Amazon EC2 management console
- Add an **Inbound rule on Port 5432** from your IP address (or `0.0.0.0/0`, which is the whole Internet, but that is much less secure)
- In the Amazon RDS management console, Modify the database and **change the security group** to this new security group (and remove the `default` security group)

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified the port inside the psycopg2 connect function.

Comment: Since he is using the default port, he doesn't need to specify it.

Comment: @jjanes he should try it